# How to run a piece of code when an element is present in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here's my code:

```
for x in range(10):
        qtitle = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='prompt-row']/div/div"))).text)
        if qtitle == en1:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='boxes']/div/div[4]/input").send_keys(fr1)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
        elif qtitle == en2:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='boxes']/div/div[4]/input").send_keys(fr2)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
```

```
        qtitle = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='prompt-row']/div/div"))).text)
        if qtitle == en1:
            driver.find_element_by_name(fr1).click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
        elif qtitle == en2:
            driver.find_element_by_name(fr2).click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
```

I want to run the first block of code only when a specific element is present on the website, and same with the second block. So, for example, when the code detects that [element1] is present it will run the first block of code, whilst when [element2] is present it will run the code below it. Is there a way to do this? I thought about using WebDriverWait, so the code would look like this:

```
for x in range(10):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visisbility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element1 xpath")))
        qtitle = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='prompt-row']/div/div"))).text)
        if qtitle == en1:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='boxes']/div/div[4]/input").send_keys(fr1)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
        elif qtitle == en2:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='boxes']/div/div[4]/input").send_keys(fr2)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visisbility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element2 xpath")))
        qtitle = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='prompt-row']/div/div"))).text)
        if qtitle == en1:
            driver.find_element_by_name(fr1).click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
        elif qtitle == en2:
            driver.find_element_by_name(fr2).click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prompt-area']/button").click()
            time.sleep(1)
```

But it just ends up waiting for [element1] to be located because it works top to bottom. Any help solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Does element 1, element 2 has any special attributes like class, name or id? if so, you can find the common parent element and check the presence of attributes in the child elements. Based on the attribute value, you can execute different blocks of code.

Comment: Yes, they both have special classes. What code would you write to implement this?

Comment: I will write a sample solution in the answer section

Comment: The first suggestion is to decrease the `Wait` time from 20 to 5 (if it suits you). and then wrap your code around try/catch block. In try put the 1st scenario and in the catch block put the 2nd scenario.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have page html source like this,

```
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child1'> </div>
<div class='child2'> </div>
<div class='child3'> </div>
</div>
```

You can dynamically check what type of child nodes present in the html.

```
parent = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='parent']")))
val = "None"
#now find all the child elements in the parent
for child in parent.find_elements(By.XPATH('*')):
    val = child.get_attribute("class or id or name")
    if val == 'child1':
        #Execute your block of code
    elif val == "Child2":
        #Execute your block of code
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might work- however there's one issue. The website uses javascript, so the child element changes each time. There's also no other identifying feature that connect them (ie class or id) except them both being under the same parent. Is there a way to return all the elements under that parent without identifying them via class or id or name etc?

Comment: parent.find_elements(By.XPATH('*')) - actually returns a list of all child elements underneath the parent.

Comment: Now it just comes up with the error 'File "C:\Users\lycop\desktop\{file name}", line 53, in <module>
    for child in parent.find_elements(By.XPATH('*')):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

Comment: is your parent a webelement or a string object? check your code.

Comment: This is the xpath for the parent '//*[@id="boxes"]' however it doesn't show it on the website- just its children

Comment: You have to find the parent element which contains all the child elements which you want to loop through. In the above example - "//div[@class='parent']"